# Como devolver un observable en Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo varios controles que se subscriben a un servicio http que devuelve los datos de un proyecto de acuerdo al codigo de proyecto, llamadas de este tipo:

```
this.proyectosService.getByCodigo('xxx').subscribe(response => {
    // hacer algo
});
```

el metodo del servicio no es nada de otro mundo:

```
public getByCodigo(codigo: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + codigo).map(response => response.json());
}
```

La cuestión es que estoy viendo que se realizan demasiadas peticiones seguidas, a la misma url por lo que para optimizar tiempos se me ocurre que podria guardar dentro de la memoria del servicio el ultimo objeto devuelto y antes de consultar al servidor corroborar si el objecto solicitado es el que tengo en memoria (comparar el codigo de proyecto), el problema es que no se como devolver en caso que ya tenga en memoria el objeto como un observable de manera que sea trasparente para los controles que se subscriben al servicio, la idea es hacer algo asi:

```
 public getByCodigo(codigo: string) {
    if (this.ultimoProyecto.codigo === codigo) {
        // aqui el problema como devuelvo los datos
    } else {
        return this.http.get(this.url + codigo).map(response => {
            this.ultimoProyecto = response.json() // actualizo referencia al ultimo devuelto
            return response.json();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me auto respondo con la solución que he encontrado hasta el momento y me ha funcionado, al final solo era devolver un observable.

```
public getByCodigo(codigo: string) {
    if (this.ultimoProyecto.codigo === codigo) {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
                return observer.next(this.ultimoProyecto);
            });
    } else {
        return this.http.get(this.url + codigo).map(response => {
            this.ultimoProyecto = response.json() // actualizo referencia al ultimo devuelto
            return response.json();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza un array asociativo y si ya existe el código devuelve el valor del índice según el código ya almacenado en el, sino créalo, insértalo y retórnalo.

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class ProyectosService {

  private baseUrl: string = environment.baseUrl;
  private ultimoProyectoConCodigo = [];

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public getByCodigo(codigo: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.ultimoProyectoConCodigo[codigo] || this.ultimoProyectoConCodigo[codigo] = 
        this.http.get(this.baseUrl+codigo)
          .map((res: Response) => res.json())
          .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

 }
```

> Otra opción mucho mejor sería utilizar Redux.js: [enlace](https://medium.com/react-redux/introducci%C3%B3n-a-redux-js-8bdf4fe0751e).

Comment: cuando intento traer el que tengo en memoria me tira el error  `this.subProyectoService.getByCodigo(...).subscribe is not a function`

Comment: Alguien podría explicarme que significa exactamente esta linea:  public getByCodigo(codigo: string): Observable<any>  ? estoy comenzando con angular y no entiendo mucho los observables ( y eso que he leído varios posts sobre ellos), esa linea indica que la funcion getByCodigo retorna un observable ? gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.